# Converting Hair Particle to Mesh - Strip Shape Type

Tags: mesh, particles, bezier-curves, hair

I am aware of how many similar threads there are to this.
I came close to an answer however blender may have changed drastically since because I can no longer convert from Mesh to Curve.
[image]

Once I convert the particles the scene with blades of grass turns it to Edges without any faces
[image]

And I have tried selecting the mesh and converting it back to a curve so that i can give it depth but 1. The option to do so does not seem to be available and 2. I fear it would not keep the shape and also the colour of the grass (I used an image with emission on the emitter plane)

Hopefully the below is demonstration enough of how the particle system is set up.
[image]

[image]